# Reading data from raster layer obtained via WMS in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, wms, geoprocessing

I need to use some geological data from the WMS service `http://mapas.igme.es/gis/services/oneGeology/IGME_EN_Geology/MapServer/WMSServer` using QGIS. I've connected to the service and I can see the provided layers and if I click in the map for information I obtain the data OBJECTID, SHAPE, etc. But now I need to do some processing using Python and I'm a bit confused.

I've selected the active layer via

```
lyr = self.iface.activeLayer()
```

and I've discovered that the layer is raster. This is confusing for me because when I ask for information of an element by clickink in the map I obtain the field SHAPE as Polygon.

Well, I accept the layer is raster, so I will try to read the data. If I ask for information as

```
print(lyr.extent())
```

I obtain the rectangle limits that enclose the data in the layer. But if I try

```
print(lyr.width(),lyr.height())
```

I obtain

```
(0, 0)
```

Is this output correct or should be the number of columns and rows of the raster? Also, if I try

```
ident=lyr.dataProvider().identify(QgsPoint(-8.3,43.0),QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue)
print ident.results()
```

I obtain

```
{}
```

but if I click in the map at coordinates (-8.3,43.0) I obtain correct results.

Is it possible to iterate over all pixels in a raster layer from a WMS service using Python in QGIS?

Comment: I think it should be impossible to get data from a WMS service: this because a WMS Service returns an image; instead, it would be using WCS or WFS services...

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to iterate over all pixels in a raster layer from a WMS service using Python in QGIS?

Certainly it should be possible, but whether it will be useful is another matter because, as mentioned in comments, the principal output of an WMS (through the GetMap operation) is an image, which is a representation of the data. In other words the pixels of the image represent some symbolization of the data and don't give you access to the data itself.  If you want the data then ideally you would want a WCS or WFS, but the Geological Survey of Spain isn't providing one here so, that option is not available to you.

A secondary (optional) operation of a WMS is GetFeatureInfo, this allows for every pixel coordinate in the generated GetMap image a request for information from the underlying dataset.

If we look at the [GetCapabilities response](http://mapas.igme.es/gis/services/oneGeology/IGME_EN_Geology/MapServer/WMSServer?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities) for this service, we can see that GetFeatureInfo is supported, and allows the following media types:

```
<GetFeatureInfo>
  <Format>application/vnd.esri.wms_raw_xml</Format>
  <Format>application/vnd.esri.wms_featureinfo_xml</Format>
  <Format>application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml</Format>
  <Format>application/geojson</Format>
  <Format>text/xml</Format>
  <Format>text/html</Format>
  <Format>text/plain</Format>
```

And when I use text/html as an output I see that you get some useful information about the dataset.

`http://mapas.igme.es/gis/services/oneGeology/IGME_EN_Geology/MapServer/WmsServer?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&BBOX=38.63509725209953416,-6.31193069905889281,40.50520658115046757,-1.6816785269457486&CRS=EPSG:4258&WIDTH=1337&HEIGHT=540&LAYERS=0&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&QUERY_LAYERS=0&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&I=308&J=267&FEATURE_COUNT=1`

and when I use `INFO_FORMAT=application/geojson&` I get:

```
  {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": null,
        "properties": {
          "OBJECTID": "2748",
          "Shape": "Polygon",
          "CartoUID": "54",
          "Erathem": "Paleozoic",
          "System": "Ordovician",
          "Series": "Middle Ordovician -Upper Ordovician",
          "Description": "Slate, sandstone, quartzite and limestone or volcaniclastic rock",
          "LithoFacies": "",
          "Key_Unit": "54",
          "Symbol_S": "0000",
          "ColorNumber": "57",
          "Legend_Unit": "54 - Slate, sandstone, quartzite and limestone or volcaniclastic rock"
        },
        "layerName": "0"    
      }
    ]
  }
```

So rather than iterating over every pixel and taking the value of the pixel, you could iterate over every pixel and generate a GetFeatureInfo request.

Other things you may consider is generating an SLD for each lithology and sending that to the server to build up a series of requests/images that represent the geology.

And finally, do consider requesting the data directly from the Survey (there is a contact number provided in the GetCapabilities response).