# QGIS Raster layer query elevation at point

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, elevation

In QGIS 3.14 I try to get elevation data from denmarks elevation model using "[kortforsyrningen](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Kortforsyningen/)" plugin. The elevation model (layer name = 'DHM/Terræn') is added as a raster layer (`QgsRasterLayer` with `qgis._core.QgsSingleBandColorDataRenderer`)

I use this code (copied from [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/raster.html#query-values)) to extract elevation at a point in Denmark:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject
dhmLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('DHM/Terræn')[0]
x = 724501
y = 6175727
val, res = dhmLayer.dataProvider().sample(QgsPointXY(x, y), 0)
```

but all I get is `val == nan` and `res == False`.

I also tested the other way:

```
ident = dhmLayer.dataProvider().identify(QgsPointXY(x, y), QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue)
```

With similar results (`ident.result() == {}`).
`ident.error()` yields

> <QgsError: WMS provider Format not supported>

Does anyone have any hint to how to solve this?

Comment: Does `val, res = dhmLayer.dataProvider().sample(QgsPointXY(x, y), 1)` return something?

Comment: only `(val, res) = (nan, False)`

Answer (score 0):

QGIS methods that comment  `sample` and `identify` query data from images stored on physical or network.

**Is it possible to iterate over all pixels in a raster layer from a WMS service ?**

Certainly it should be possible

This question was answered here, you will see an option [Reading data from raster layer obtained via WMS in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225818/reading-data-from-raster-layer-obtained-via-wms-in-qgis)